# Android Studio Empty Attributes Window

Tags: android, android-studio

So I Recently just updated to the latest android studio. im having a problem with the attributed window. as the window itself appear but there's nothing inside of it other than the id of the object and 1 or 2 other attributes.

what i have tried :-

1-restarting
2-invalidating the cache

[The Attributes Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1A2s.png)

[[image: The Attributes windows With View all attributes]2]]

Comment: not sure why the 1st image isn't being displayed

Comment: have you tried to switch to text view then to design view?

Comment: i just tried , it didn't work .

Comment: i can still edit the properties from the text view but sometimes its just annoying specially with buttons and onClick Events

Comment: wow a downvote. for no reason or no comment at-all yay ...

Comment: maybe because he want to achieve a badge :)

Comment: yah i guess.  btw how do you pump posts here and is it even allowed ?